# Get the first directory of a path in GO

Tags: go, path, split, slice, filepath

In Go, is it possible to get the root directory of a path so that

`foo/bar/file.txt`

returns `foo`? I know about path/filepath, but

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
        parts := filepath.SplitList("foo/bar/file.txt")
        fmt.Println(parts[0])
        fmt.Println(len(parts))
}
```

prints `foo/bar/file.txt` and `1` whereas I would have expected `foo` and `3`.

Comment: from the docs: > SplitList splits a list of paths joined by the OS-specific ListSeparator, usually found in PATH or GOPATH environment variables.

Comment: ooops. that explains a lot

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply use [`strings.Split()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split):

```
s := "foo/bar/file.txt"
parts := strings.Split(s, "/")
fmt.Println(parts[0], len(parts))
fmt.Println(parts)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/qVNXZItXU2)):

```
foo 3
[foo bar file.txt]
```

**Note:**

If you want to split by the path separator of the current OS, use [`os.PathSeparator`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#PathSeparator) as the separator:

```
parts := strings.Split(s, string(os.PathSeparator))
```

[`filepath.SplitList()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#SplitList) splits multiple joined paths into separate paths. It does not split one path into folders and file. For example:

```
fmt.Println("On Unix:", filepath.SplitList("/a/b/c:/usr/bin"))
```

Outputs:

```
On Unix: [/a/b/c /usr/bin]
```

Comment: I actually wanted to avoid that due to path separator differences on windows and linux. Is there a solution in the standard library for that?

Comment: @Stefan: then use `os.PathSeparator `

Comment: os.PathSeparator is an int so it needs to be converted.

Comment: Thanks new to go as well i didn't know iw was as simple as that to cast it to a string.

Comment: Using `strings.Split` will produce an empty string as the first item when used with an absolute UNIX path. Furthermore it produces two empty strings when used with specific Windows paths.

Here is an example:
https://go.dev/play/p/jlBWsVEAzlG

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you just need the first part, `strings.SplitN` is at least 10 times
faster from my testing:

```
package main
import "strings"

func main() {
   parts := strings.SplitN("foo/bar/file.txt", "/", 2)
   println(parts[0] == "foo")
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/strings#SplitN