# Retrieve first directory in URL-like string in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to obtain the first directory in an URL-like string like this: `"/blog/:year/:daynum/:postname"`. I thought splitting it, then retrieving the first directory, would be this simple. But it returns square brackets surrounding the string even though it's not a slice. How can I get that first directory? (I am guaranteed that the string starts with a "/" followed by a valid directory designation and that contains both a leading directory and a string using those permalink properties).

What's the best way to parse out that first directory?

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)
// Retrieve the first directory in the URL-like
// string passed in
func firstDir(permalink string) string {
    split := strings.Split(permalink, "/")
    return string(fmt.Sprint((split[0:2])))
}
func main() {
    permalink := "/blog/:year/:daynum/:postname"
    dir := firstDir(permalink)
    fmt.Printf("leading dir is: %s.", dir)
    // Prints NOT "blog" but "[ blog]".
}
```

Comment: `split[0:2]` is a slice with two elements. You split by "/" so the entire array would look like: `[ blog :year :daynum :postname]`; then you take slice of first two items - so `[ blog]` (first element is empty as there's nothing in front of first "/"). To get just first element (ignoring leading empty `""`) do simply `split[1]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the first directory of a path in GO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618967/get-the-first-directory-of-a-path-in-go)

Comment: Thanks. Both of these still include the brackets in the result, but stt106's answer below showed the bare directory as required. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70342730/478311

Comment: they show brackets because you print slices and not strings (split[1] is string but split[0:2] is slice of strings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said:"(I am guaranteed that the string starts with a "/" followed by a valid directory designation and that contains both a leading directory and a string using those permalink properties)"

Then simply use `split[1]` to get the root directory.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func firstDir(permalink string) string {
    split := strings.Split(permalink, string(os.PathSeparator))
    return split[1]
}
func main() {
    permalink := "/blog/:year/:daynum/:postname"
    dir := firstDir(permalink)
    fmt.Printf("leading dir is: %s.", dir)
    // Prints "blog".
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/hCHnrDIsWYE

Comment: Beautiful, and thanks for reminding me to use os.PathSeparator (which I had removed at one point in an orgy of unsuccessful and increasingly desparate experimentation).